# change windows kit common installation path

Tags: windows, sdk

i'm trying to install Windows SDK and my main drive (C) is full. I want to change the path of the installation but it's gray , it's says that ot using the common installation path of Windows kit's path,
is there anyway to change this path?[image]

???

Comment: sombody????????

Comment: Have you solved this? I've changed everything in registry and... it does not help :-(

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me is to uninstall all Windows Software Development Kits, and the Windows SDK AddOn.  (I also uninstalled all instances of Visual Studio beforehand, but I believe that might be unnecessary.)

Then I went into the registry and I changed some of the values under here:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots
```

On my Windows 10 Pro (v 1809) machine, I had 3 values to change.  Here I am showing the default values, and I believe the trailing backslash is important.

```
KitsRoot    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\
KitsRoot10  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
KitsRoot81  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
```

After modifying these values, I could re-install a kit into the appropriate folder (matching the registry values that I had set).

This also fixes one of the unmodifiable paths for the Visual Studio Professional 2017 installation (presumably it relies on the same registry keys).

Comment: Thanks, this also helped for another issue where i found installation location is set ti O: driver, weird!!

Comment: @Shay thanks for clarifying that VS uninstallation was unnecessary.   I have slightly edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and type `cd (path to installer)`.

Then type `(installer name) /installpath (any path)`.

Like this:
`EmulatorSetup.exe /installpath D:\software\Win10Dev\HoloLens\Emulator`

(In this case I am using the HoloLens emulator, but this will work with any Windows Kits installer)

Comment: This apparently doesn't work; even if you uninstall previous SDK installations, the setup complains there is an already installed version at the original path, and therefore cannot be changed. Using symlinks/junctions also doesn't work, because the setup checks the disk's remaining space and can't be forced to ignore it.